# System's property page is ignored by msbuild.exe

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I'm trying to run an automated build from the command line, using `MSBuild.exe`. One of my projects is relying on a user macro from `%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user.props` for its `libpath`.

I can build the project in VS2010 without problems, but when trying to build it from command-line it fails.

Is it possible that the above property page file is only relevant to the IDE?!

Comment: It turns out that MSBuild must be given the current path as root, or else it will fail to find these itself. Adding the MSBuild option `/p:UserRootDir=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0` solved the issue!

Comment: It should work without specifying it.
In vcxproj file, before Import of Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props there should be 
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
This file "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" defines 
<UserRootDir Condition="'$(UserRootDir)' == '' ">$(LocalAppData)\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0</UserRootDir>
Possible causes:
-already defined env.variable named UserRootDir
-changed env. variable LocalAppData
on WinXP LocalAppData is not defined, but msbuild can deal with it(tested on fully updated Win)

Answer (score 3):

By default user props file (Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props) is imported directly inside vcxproj file. The default condition says it is always imported. Check your vcxproj.

```
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
```

Do you build your project file under the same user?

Can you please specify your command line you use to build project?

When VC project is build from IDE VS specifies property BuildingInsideVisualStudio to indicate that it is building from IDE.